# deleting a record just refreshing the page in php

Tags: php

Trying to delete a record but it is just refreshing the page.Deleting a record need to update the status to 0 but it is just refreshing the page not updating any data

```
<td>
   <a class="buttons delete" href="deletequestions.php?id='.$row['question_number'] .'">
      <i class="fa fa-trash"> </i>
   </a>
</td>
```

Deletequestions.php

```
<?php
     session_start();
     include 'includes/db.php';
     $id=$_REQUEST['question_number'];
     $query1 = "UPDATE  questions set status='0' WHERE question_number=$id ";
     $result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query1);
     header("Location: searchquestions.php");
?>
```

Questions DB Table:

questions_number   text       status

1               question1     1

2                 question2     1

Choices DB Table:

id  questions_number   is_correct    text     status

1    1                   0         question     1

2    1                   1         question     1

3    1                   0         question     1

4    2                   0         question1    1

5    2                   1         question2    1

6    2                   0         question3    1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the variable you pass to the page is `id` not `question_number` in the url, as you used `?id=`

`$id=$_REQUEST['question_number'];`

should be :

`$id=$_REQUEST['id'];`

Comment: I see no choices table in your question... If you need to update another table you should add a second query after the first.

Comment: I am inserting multiple choices answers in another table "choices" by adding question_number as a foreign key

Comment: So once user deletes a record all the status related to that questions should be updated as zero.

Comment: so add :
$query2 = "UPDATE  choices set status='0' WHERE question_number=$id ";
$result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query2);